# In Spark, is there a way to view the "percent of progress" on a DataFrame action in the History Server while it's in-progress?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For a long-running .write operation, want to get an idea what "part" of the operation the cluster is working on. I know that in the history server, you can see the list of active and completed jobs as well as a dag and text-based query plan.

However, there doesn't seem to be:

- A static notion of "how many jobs there are" -- new jobs and stages will get added over time,  I think due to the Adaptive Query Plan.
- An indicator of which nodes in the full query plan are "complete" -- they're all highlighted in the same blue with no additional details. Row count, compute hours, etc. only appear when the job is complete.

And the "Completed Job Ids" don't seem to be the same IDs as the integers that appear next to the Physical or Logical plan, or the plan's "Codegen Id".

Is there a certain way I should be reading it?